# Set Background for App.RootFrame from App.Resources in wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Friends,

I am assigning the `Background` of `RootFrame` to application resources, It works when you explicitly write the Resource name like below

```
App.RootFrame.Background = (System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush)App.Current.Resources["Theme_6"];
```

but If I use below it doesn't work:

```
string themeName = "Theme_6";
App.RootFrame.Background = (System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush)App.Current.Resources[themeName];
```

Is it possible to use the 2nd options in wp8?

Thanks!

Comment: There must be something else happening to explain a difference in behavior. You may need to provide more details/more code. When you step through the code in the 2nd case, is `themeName` set correctly? Is there someplace else that might be changing the behavior?

Comment: Thanks, I have this statement only in constructor of `App`

Comment: If you're suggesting there's a difference between a hard-coded `string` literal and a variable string for the issue you're having, there's got to be something else causing the actual issue. It's not this as presented.

Answer (score 0):

Panorama control (and I think Pivot controls as well) has some problem supporting late binding for background images.
When you hard-code the image paths, there is no problem displaying a static background image.

To assign background images 'on the fly' you should follow these steps;

- Create a Property (MainBackGroundImage) within your associated
  ViewModel, that implements INotifyPropertyChanged interface (if you
  are using MVVM pattern you already have this infrastructure).
- Assign any image path (this can be a remote URL as well) to this
  property whenever you want to change the background image.
- In your View hook up to your ViewModel's property changed event and
  update the layout of the control where background image is going to
  appear:

  ```
  void viewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender,PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {

  if (e.PropertyName == “MainBackGroundImage”)
  {
        this.MainPanorama.UpdateLayout();
  }
  }
  ```

You might perhaps take a look at my [open-source WP8 application](https://phoneguitartab.codeplex.com) where I did achieve dynamic background images.

Comment: Thanks I got your point, but I don't have panorama control in my app. The issue is I don't want to set every page background with MVVM and call it in every page. I would like to set it only once in app.XAML or App.XAML.CS and the rest should do the work for me. You are setting background for a Grid or may be contents, but I am looking to set background for whole application.